# Placing SQL Server generated emails in Outlook Outbox

Tags: sql-server, outlook

We send monthly emails generated in SQL Server(2017) using sp_send_dbmail to clients containing sensitive data. Recently, there's been a breach where a client received something they shouldn't have received. The cause of this is honestly just bad code, but going forward we want to be able to screen emails more effectively. We are now avoiding the sensitive data issue by asking clients to log in to our system to look at this data instead. Whilst this would be perfectly normal procedure, certain people demand everything in an email. It's a security problem, but the client wants what they want, and the head honcho wants to give the client what they want.

We use Outlook, which has an outbox that nobody really uses anymore as far as I know. Is there a way to get SQL Server to place emails into a shared outbox account so that we can screen emails that contain sensitive data before we send them out?

For initial QA, data for emails containing alerts are generated via stored procedures and sent to QA analysts to check over. This is done by manually setting the recipients to the QA analysts for emails to all clients.

We don't expect them to cover every email as that would be insane, so we ask that they check a random selection to be confident enough that the data is accurate.

Once they are happy, we run the stored procedures again but we pass a parameter so that it cursors through a table that contains every email alert for each client and generates the tailored email for each client and is sent using sp_send_dbmail.

In other words, the email being screened by the QA analysts might not be the same as the email send to clients. This is how the breach occurred.

If we had a way to get these emails into a shared outbox, the QA work can be done on that shared outbox and then we can send the emails. Asking someone to hit send for a big bunch of emails would still be a pain, but perhaps a little less so than having another breach.

Comment: Why not just bcc that account in the emails you send?

Comment: The idea is to screen emails *before* they are sent, so I don't think BCC would work.

Comment: Then send them to that account, and then have a human being forward them once they are signed off? Honestly, this seems like you just shouldn't be pandering to the request; sometimes you *have* to force clients to do the better thing.

Comment: Having a human being forward the emails is no small undertaking - we are talking hundreds if not thousands of emails.

I don't disagree that forcing the client to do the right thing is what we should do, but unfortunately this isn't my decision to make.

Comment: So how does it get signed off? Machine Learning? AI?

Comment: I've edited the main post.

Comment: This sounds more like that you need to do the initial testing and then have a **documented** sign off procedure. Only once the process has been signed off can emails for that process go "live" and they are sent to the client. This all smells like an XY problem](//xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: If you could generate all emails (in final form with data, attachments etc already in place) into some intermediate table, then send them to your shadow mailbox, then check them and if they look OK, then send same emails to intended recipients? (If they do not look OK, then just start over.)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `sp_send_dbmail` uses SMTP to send messages. If you want to place messages in the Drafts (or any other) folder of a particular mailbox, you will need to create messages (without sending) using Graph or EWS.